# EBS volume in Autoscaling not getting attached

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create 2 ebs volume in an autoscaling environment where I am launching 2 instances.

Currently, this user data ps script is able to check and get into an else loop, if there is no "available" volume. But it is creating only 2 volumes instead of 4 because (2 for each instance). Do I need to put sleep condition? How 2 ebs volumes will get attached to 2 separate instances launched by auto-scaling?

```
   $instanceId = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id;                         

   $available = Get-EC2Volume -Filter @{ Name="status"; Values="available" }

   if($available) {
       Get-EC2Volume -Filter @{ Name="status"; Values="available" } >> c:\cfn\scripts\volumeinfo.txt;          
       $vid = Get-Content "c:\cfn\scripts\volumeinfo.txt" | select-string volumeId | Foreach-Object { $_.ToString().split(':')[1] -replace '\s','' }
       Add-Content -Path c:\cfn\scripts\info.txt -Value $vid
       [Byte] $c = [Char] 'd';
       foreach ($volumeid in $vid) {                                                 
                    Add-Content -Path c:\cfn\scripts\info.txt -Value $volumeid                                                       
                    $instanceId = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id 
                    Add-EC2Volume -InstanceId $instanceId -VolumeId $volumeid -Device "/dev/sd$([Char] $c++)" }
       Get-Disk | Where-Object IsOffline –Eq $True | Set-Disk –IsOffline $False             

  } else {
      echo "Else Loop" >> c:\cfn\scripts\info.txt;
      $instanceId = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id
      $rgn = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone
      $v = New-EC2Volume -AvailabilityZone $rgn -Size 50 -VolumeType gp2                  
      Add-EC2Volume -Device /dev/sdb -InstanceId $instanceId -VolumeId $v.VolumeId
      Add-Content -Path c:\cfn\scripts\info.txt -Value $v.VolumeId

      $v = New-EC2Volume -AvailabilityZone $rgn -Size 50 -VolumeType gp2                  
      Add-EC2Volume -Device /dev/sdc -InstanceId $instanceId -VolumeId $v.VolumeId
      Add-Content -Path c:\cfn\scripts\info.txt -Value $v.VolumeId        
      Get-Disk | Where-Object IsOffline –Eq $True | Set-Disk –IsOffline $False
```

Answer (score 0):

May be add `Get-EC2Volume` and wait for the status to become `available` and then attach it to the EC2 instance. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/Index.html

Comment: Thanks for the response.Is there any condition which I can put as when the first instance user data finish then only for the second instance it should run..I believe due to launch configuration both the instances are running simultaneously which is causing the issue?  Any advice would be helpful

Comment: that should not be the issue.

Comment: I just tested the first instance is going in first loop and second instance is going in else loop. Thinking how we can fix this :( May be I have to remove sleep conditions which I just added ... Thanks for the respone

Comment: In Launchconfiguration is there any way we can launch one instance after the other? Like depends on something?